# Discord.Net C# Sharded Bot Unknown Dispatch (INVITE_CREATE)

Tags: c#, discord.net

Each of my shards spit out this message: 19:49:31 Shard #81    Unknown Dispatch (INVITE_CREATE) after a user uses a command to get an invite for a server. Is there any more information on this?

It also looks like I also get something similar where instead its (INVITE_DELETE).

Comment: Those events are new and the lib has not been updated to handle them. That's the default way that it handles `Unknown` events.

Comment: That's what I figured. This was resolved by updating the lib to the latest nightly build.